# N-Queens, bitwise approach

Tags: python, recursion, bitwise, n-queens

I've recently solved the famous *N-Queens problem*:

> Can you place \$N\$ chess queens on a \$N × N\$ board in such a way that no one
>   attacks another queen?

The idea here is based on the ideas from several blogposts describing a bitwise approach - approaching the board row by row, keeping track of bits of 3 numbers - columns, major and minor diagonals:

```
class Solution(object):
    def totalNQueens(self, n):
        all_ones = 2 ** n - 1

        def helper(ld, column, rd, count=0):
            if column == all_ones:  # filled out all vacant positions
                return 1

            possible_slots = ~(ld | column | rd)  # mark possible vacant slots as 1s
            while possible_slots & all_ones:
                current_bit = possible_slots & -possible_slots  # get first 1 from the right
                possible_slots -= current_bit  # occupy a slot

                # mark conflicts in the next row
                next_column_bit = column | current_bit
                next_rd_bit = (rd | current_bit) << 1
                next_ld_bit = (ld | current_bit) >> 1

                count += helper(next_ld_bit, next_column_bit, next_rd_bit)
            return count

        return helper(0, 0, 0)
```

The solution was accepted by the [LeetCode OJ](https://leetcode.com/problems/n-queens-ii/) and actually *beats 98.97% of Python solutions*. But, can we optimize it even further? What would you improve code-quality/readability wise?

Another follow-up concern is that I don't see an easy way for this problem to instead of counting possible board arrangements, collect all possible distinct board configurations.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Micro-optimizing Python is a bit of a quixotic endeavour — if you wanted the fastest possible performance then you wouldn't be using Python. But so long as we understand the nature of the exercise, then it's just a matter of trying lots of changes and measuring the results to see which ones are improvements:

Here's the baseline measurement for comparison with the improvements:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit(lambda:totalNQueens(13), number=1)
4.241301966001629
```

1. Move the mask against `all_ones` out of the loop. That is, instead of:

   ```
   possible_slots = ~(ld | column | rd)
   while possible_slots & all_ones:
   ```

   write:

   ```
   possible_slots = ~(ld | column | rd) & all_ones
   while possible_slots:
   ```

   This saves about 6%:

   ```
   >>> timeit(lambda:totalNQueens(13), number=1)
   3.999626944991178
   ```
2. Accumulate `count` via a variable local to `totalNQueens` instead of returning it from `helper`:

   ```
   def totalNQueens(n):
       all_ones = 2 ** n - 1
       count = 0

       def helper(ld, column, rd):
           nonlocal count
           if column == all_ones:
               count += 1
               return
           possible_slots = ~(ld | column | rd) & all_ones
           while possible_slots:
               current_bit = possible_slots & -possible_slots
               possible_slots -= current_bit
               next_column_bit = column | current_bit
               next_rd_bit = (rd | current_bit) << 1
               next_ld_bit = (ld | current_bit) >> 1
               helper(next_ld_bit, next_column_bit, next_rd_bit)

       helper(0, 0, 0)
       return count
   ```

   This saves another 3% or so:

   ```
   >>> timeit(lambda:totalNQueens(13), number=1)
   3.8595934879995184
   ```
3. Avoid the local variables `next_column_bit` and so on:

   ```
   def totalNQueens(n):
       all_ones = 2 ** n - 1
       count = 0

       def helper(ld, column, rd):
           nonlocal count
           if column == all_ones:
               count += 1
               return
           possible_slots = ~(ld | column | rd) & all_ones
           while possible_slots:
               current_bit = possible_slots & -possible_slots
               possible_slots -= current_bit
               helper((ld | current_bit) >> 1,
                      column | current_bit,
                      (rd | current_bit) << 1)

       helper(0, 0, 0)
       return count
   ```

   This saves roughly another 4%:

   ```
   >>> timeit(lambda:totalNQueens(13), number=1)
   3.706758002997958
   ```

That's about 13% improvement in all.

Answer (score 5):

> What would you improve code-quality/readability wise?

Firstly, documentation. The existing comments help a bit, but mainly as aids to reverse engineering the meaning of the variables and the helper method. Three lines of documentation explaining the arguments and return value of `helper` would be a big improvement.

Secondly, the names.

- I suspect that `Solution` and `totalNQueens` are imposed on you by the online judge, but if not then `Solution` is a remarkably uninformative name and I'd favour something like `NQueens.totalSolutions(...)`.
- `n` is perfectly reasonable, and `all_ones` is descriptive.
- `helper` is informative enough given its scope.
- `ld` and `rd` had me puzzled for a while until I figured out that they're probably short for *left diagonal* and *right diagonal*.
- `column` misled me completely: I initially assumed it would range from `0` to `n-1` and that you were filling in queens column-by-column rather than row-by-row.
- `count` is a reasonable name, but I'm not sure why it's an argument rather than a local variable.
- `possible_slots` sounds self-documenting, but what is a slot?
- `current_bit` at least hints at the range of values, but what's the difference between `bit` and `slot`?
- `next_column_bit`, `next_rd_bit`, and `next_ld_bit` all sound like they should have a single bit set, but actually they're more complicated masks.

I would favour names like `column_mask`, `major_diag_mask`, `minor_diag_mask`, `possible_columns`, `selected_column`.

---

> Another follow-up concern is that I don't see an easy way for this problem to instead of counting possible board arrangements, collect all possible distinct board configurations.

The standard approaches for counting distinct configurations are:

1. Rather than counting configurations, generate them; then find a canonical representation and add that to a `set`.
2. Ensure that you only generate the canonical representative of each equivalence class in the first place.
3. Count them (generating if you must), but at the same time count symmetries, and record counts per symmetry. Then divide the count for each symmetry by the size of its symmetry group and sum.
4. Run various counts, one per symmetry, and then account for the double-counting.

If we consider the last one, because I think it will require the least adaptation: what symmetries can a solution have? The square has eight symmetries:

```
AB  AC  BD  BA  CA  CD  DB  DC
CD  BD  AC  DC  DB  AB  CA  BA
```

However, a solution for `n > 1` cannot have horizontal or vertical mirror symmetry, because that would require both that `n` be odd and that all queens be on the central column/row; it can't have diagonal symmetry, because that would require that all queens be on the same major or minor diagonal; so we're left with rotations. There are three possibilities: no rotational symmetry (so `totalNQueens` finds 8 equivalent solutions), rotational symmetry of order 2 (it finds 4 equivalent solutions), or rotational symmetry of order 4 (it finds 2 equivalent solutions).

It may be possible to argue further that for some sizes rotations are impossible; alternatively you could try to just assume that they are possible and count them. A relatively simple modification for the "just count" approach would require shifting everything left by `n` bits so that you can mark "future" diagonals as used and tracking both the current row and a mask of rows which already have their queen by symmetry.

Comment: Great review, thank you! I was actually subconsciously hoping for someone to mention symmetry! It appears that we can still use symmetry for odd squares as well, this is a good read on how to do it: http://liujoycec.github.io/2015/09/20/n_queens_symmetry/.

Comment: @alecxe, I think you're reading something into my comments about symmetry which I don't think is there. That blog post is about using something along the lines of the second standard approach I mentioned in order to speed up counting all solutions; my comments are about implementing the fourth standard approach in order to count distinct solutions.